# Is there any way to convert MSSQL script to PostgreSQL script?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I need to convert this procedure from MSSQL into PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUserPhone
    @PhoneNumber        varchar(255)    output,
    @BIC            integer,
    @Rest           numeric(9,4)    output
AS
BEGIN
    select @PhoneNumber = @PhoneNumber
    select @Rest = 600.889
    INSERT INTO CallLimit
           (Phone ,Limit)
    VALUES
           (@PhoneNumber,18655)
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure makes no sense to me. It's called **Get**UserPhone, but as far as I can tell it doesn't "get" anything, it merely **inserts** a new row.

Declaring `@PhoneNumber` as an `OUT` parameter does not seem to make any sense either. The output value is simply set to the input value (if I understand that code correctly). `@BIC` is not used, so it can be removed completely.

As far as I can tell this can be converted to something like this:

```
create or replace procedure insert_call_limit(p_phone_number text, inout p_rest numeric)
as
$$
begin
  insert into call_limit (phone, limit)
  values (p_phone_number, 18655);
  p_rest := 600.889
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

As the procedure only seems to return a single value (`@Rest`)  I would probably turn that into a function, rather than using dubious OUT parameter.

If you need more details, please refer to the [PL/pgSQL reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is at least one way: to convert manually Transact SQL code to PL/pgSQL code
which is PostgreSQL default procedural language. PostgreSQL has stored procedures since version 11 (for older version you need to use stored functions).

The documentation has no example for converting Transact-SQL to PL/pgSQL but has some examples to convert Oracle PL/SQL to PL/pgSQL: see [PG docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-porting.html).